# Example of passing an empty array to a function, inputting values in that function and returning values

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I'm supposed to create an empty array in the main function and then use two separate functions to 1. accept inputs into the array and then 2. display values of the array.

Here is what I've come up with and I'm getting conversion errors along the lines of invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]. However, our class doesn't get to pointers until two weeks from now and this is due next week, so I assume we are not to get into using pointers yet.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int inputFoodAmounts(int[]);
int foodFunction(int[]);


int main()
{

    int num[7];

    cout << "Enter pounds of food";
    inputFoodAmounts(num[7]);
    foodFunction(num[7]);

    return 0;

}

int inputFoodAmounts(int num[]) 
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter pounds of food";
        cin >> num[i];
    }
}

int foodFunction(int num[])
{
    for (int j = 1; j < 7; j++)
    {   

        cout << num[j];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `num` to the functions; `num[7]` means the 8th element of the array (and it's out of the bound of the array) but not the array itself. Change it to

```
inputFoodAmounts(num);
foodFunction(num);
```

---

BTW: `for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)` looks weird because it only iterates the array from the 2nd element to the 7th one.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the sloppiness, I just wanted to make a quick example work through hints without actually posting the homework. Now I think i've got the basics down.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void inputFoodAmounts(int[]);                                           //made these two functions void you were not returning anything
void foodFunction(int[]);


int main()
{

    int num[7];

    inputFoodAmounts(num);                                              //when passing arrays just send the name 
    foodFunction(num);


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}

void inputFoodAmounts(int num[])
{
    cout << "Please enter the weight of the food items: \n";            //a good practice is to always make your output readable i reorganized your outputs a bit
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)                                         //careful: you wanted a size 7 array but you started index i at 1 and less than 7 so that will only give you
    {                                                                   // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 -> so only 6 
        cout << "Food "<<i +1 <<": ";
        cin >> num[i];                                                  
    }
}

void foodFunction(int num[])
{
    cout << "Here are the weight you entered: \n";
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
    {

        cout << "Food "<<j+1<<": "<<num[j]<<" pounds\n";
    }
}
```

I believe you were getting invalid type error because you were passing your array `num[7]`.

Comment: When you pass an array to a function you pass it as a pointer - what you did in your original code was `inputFoodAmounts(num[7])` What you did was pass the value that was stored in the 7th index of the array which in this case was of type `int`. That was probably why you were getting the error. Hope this helped :D